# extra zero as output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()

{
char *str="Helloworld";
printf("%d",printf("%s",str));
return 0;
}
```

output of this program is Helloworld10 instead of Helloworld1
from where that miscellaneous zero comes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you like the program to write `Helloworld1`? What should that 1 come from?
[the return value of functions of the `printf` family is the number of characters outputted](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) (except the final `\0` for the variants like `sprintf`). `Helloworld` has length 10.

Comment: (The final `\0` is not outputted)

Answer (score 1):

printf returns the number of written characters.